# how to have a shared variable in library across many applications in linux?

Tags: c++, linux

how to have a shared variable in library across all application in linux (c++)?

Comment: The given answers already offer some ways to do it. But the real question is why would you want to do that in the first place? If we knew that we may be able to come up with a cleaner and maybe even easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use POSIX shared memory to create a shared memory segment, and place the variable there.  You will need to synchronise access to the shared variable using POSIX semaphores.

See the [shm_overview(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and [sem_overview(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) man pages to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, you can use posix shared memory or just mmap() a file and have the variable exist in that area of memory.

The loader will not automatically do this with a special section such as the "shared" one in Win32 DLLs. This is probably not a big deal as it's a bit of an anti-feature anyway.