# How to create a shared memory segment that can be accessed by multiple processes

Tags: c++, linux

We have got quite familiar to shared data accessed by multiple threads within a single process. But how can we make a piece of memory shared by multiple processes?

Comment: Google has a crapload of stuff on it. You're looking for `/dev/shm` the `shmget` man page and everything related to them. P.S. The POSIX defined interface is of course in C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to have a shared variable in library across many applications in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938244/how-to-have-a-shared-variable-in-library-across-many-applications-in-linux)

Comment: Remember that you have to be careful synchronising access to shared memory. It may be easier to use more structured mechanisms like pipes and semaphores. It might also be worth looking at [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0).

Answer (score 2):

The routine you want is `mmap`, which takes a file descriptor, and returns a pointer to a chunk of memory.  The multiple processes then all use the same filename to get to it. Of course you need to coordinate reading/writing so that nobody has to deal with corrupt data.

The filename can be that of an actual file in the file system, or it can just be a name passed to `shm_open`.

Actually, it depends on what you are trying to do. If you just `fork()` to create the additional process, the child process shares memory with the parent, with certain (documented) exceptions.  Unless and until you call `exec()`.  Using `fork()` without `exec()` can lead to myriad headaches, though, so shouldn't be done except for simple cases.

Comment: Using a file is rather clumsy; if you just want to share memory, then create a shared memory object with `shm_open` of `shmget` instead. That will work even if you don't have a writable filesystem mounted.

Comment: I didn't actually say to use a file.  Only a filename.  `shm_open` requires a filename.

Comment: The memory sharing after `fork()` is the result of a kernel optimization rather than a feature.  It is called [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)

Answer (score 1):

See [`shm_overview(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) for details, but here's a quick run-down of functions to call to create/delete an anonymous memory mapping:

- [`shm_open(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) to create and/or attach to shared memory and get a file descriptor for it
- optional [`ftruncate(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) to set the size of the memory segment when creating
- [`mmap(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to map shared memory into your process address space
- [`munmap(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/munmap.2.html) to remove the mapping from process address space
- [`shm_unlink(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/shm_unlink.3.html) to remove the shared memory segment

Answer (score 0):

For completeness with the rest of the answers, you can also manage shared memory blocks with [shmget(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shmget.2.html) for creating and [shmat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shmat.2.html) for attaching.  This is what the Linux version of Google Chrome uses to share memory among its processes.